# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:table abc has no column named xyz

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am getting following error while trying to insert records in SQLite database-

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table jolly has no column named noOfShares (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO jolly(noOfShares,id,noOfMustGos,noOfSeen,caption,noOfBeenTheres,location) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

I failed to understand why its showing column in this order:

- noOfShares
- id
- noOfMustGos
- noOfSeen
- caption
- noOfBeenTheres
- location

while I created table with different order of columns and assigning value in same order. I tried uninstalling the app and also changing table name but it didn't resolved.

Adapter:

```
VideoSql videoSql;
    public View getView(final int i, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    videoSql=new VideoSql();
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
        videoSql.setId(mVideos.get(i).getId());
        videoSql.setCaption(mVideos.get(i).getCaption());
        videoSql.setNoOfMustGos(mVideos.get(i).getNoOfMustGos());
        videoSql.setNoOfShares(mVideos.get(i).getNoOfShares());
        videoSql.setLocation(mVideos.get(i).getLocation());
        videoSql.setNoOfBeenTheres(mVideos.get(i).getNoOfBeenTheres());
        videoSql.setNoOfSeen(mVideos.get(i).getNoOfSeen());

        db.addContact(videoSql);
}
```

DatabaseHandler:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
VideoSql mvideo;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TDatabase";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_JOLLY = "jolly";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_CAPTION = "caption";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    private static final String KEY_NOSHARES = "noOfShares";
    private static final String KEY_NOBEENTHERE = "noOfBeenTheres";
    private static final String KEY_NOMUSTGO = "noOfMustGos";
    private static final String KEY_NOCOMMENTS = "noOfComments";
    private static final String KEY_NOSEEN = "noOfSeen";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "userName";
    private static final String KEY_USERID = "userId";
    private static final String KEY_TIMESTAMP ="timestamp" ;
    private static final String KEY_FOLLOWED = "followed";
    private static final String KEY_BEENTHERE = "beenThere";
    private static final String KEY_MUSTGO = "mustGo";
    private static final String KEY_NOFOLLOWED = "noOfFollowed";
    private static final String KEY_NOFOLLOWERS = "noOfFollowers";
    private static final String KEY_USERHANDLE = "userHandle";
    private static final String KEY_DTS = "dts";
    private static final String KEY_FEATURED = "featured";
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        String CREATE_JOLLY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_JOLLY + "("
                + KEY_ID +  KEY_CAPTION +  KEY_LOCATION +  KEY_NOSHARES + KEY_NOBEENTHERE +KEY_NOMUSTGO +
                 KEY_NOSEEN +")" ;
        db.execSQL(CREATE_JOLLY_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_JOLLY);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addContact(VideoSql videoSql)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, videoSql.getId());
        values.put(KEY_CAPTION, videoSql.getCaption());
        values.put(KEY_LOCATION, videoSql.getLocation());
        values.put(KEY_NOSHARES, videoSql.getNoOfShares());
        values.put(KEY_NOBEENTHERE, videoSql.getNoOfBeenTheres());
        values.put(KEY_NOMUSTGO, videoSql.getNoOfMustGos());

        values.put(KEY_NOSEEN, videoSql.getNoOfSeen());

        db.insert(TABLE_JOLLY, null, values);

        Log.e("addcontact", videoSql.getCaption());
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<VideoSql> getAllContacts() {
        List<VideoSql> contactList = new ArrayList<VideoSql>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_JOLLY;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                VideoSql videoinfo = new VideoSql();
                videoinfo.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                videoinfo.setCaption(cursor.getString(1));
                videoinfo.setLocation(cursor.getString(2));
                videoinfo.setNoOfShares(cursor.getString(3));
                videoinfo.setNoOfBeenTheres(cursor.getString(4));
                videoinfo.setNoOfMustGos(cursor.getString(5));

                videoinfo.setNoOfSeen(cursor.getString(6));


                contactList.add(videoinfo);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return contactList;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your `Column Type` ? in create able sql command

Comment: unfortunately your table is not created.

Comment: refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28599311/1576416

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma After doing this changes you must uninstall your app and install a fresh .apk built again so that create new DB with New Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually missing the each column's data type in the create table syntax.

You should create table with following syntax,

```
String CREATE_JOLLY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_JOLLY + "("
            + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
......<other column-name> <column-type>; ///
```

Note : Once you made changes suggested above, you should first remove the old application from  your device and then test it again, otherwise it will keep on giving you same error as it will not execute `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` method since it has been executed with old instance. So to execute `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)`'s code it is advisable to remove completely old application from the device and execute the code as fresh.

Comment: Can you please tell me whats errors you are getting ?

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma, did you try what I suggested ?

Answer (score 2):

Provide Column Type after Column Name in `SQL CREATE TABLE` Command like

### Example

```
String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
  + TABLE_JOLLY + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
  + KEY_CAPTION +" text not null, "
  + KEY_LOCATION +" text not null, " 
  + KEY_NOSHARES +" text not null, "
  + KEY_NOBEENTHERE +" text not null, "
  + KEY_NOMUSTGO+" text not null, "
  + KEY_NOSEEN " text not null);"
```

For info http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Thanks a lott!! +one to ur answer.i'll try tht

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma After doing this changes you must uninstall your app and install a fresh .apk built again